# How can I create block of text that ignores the surrounding glue?

Tags: spacing, boxes, paragraphs

After developing a custom environment that has both table-like data and paragraph data, I noticed some interesting effects. The glue (I think) is messing with the alignment of the text around each description. I am still learning about the switching between horizontal vertical modes.

I wrapped the paragraph data in a `\parbox`, which I guess is adding glue. You will notice that **the spacing around the description under GPU is different than around the others' descriptions**. I would like all descriptions to be top-aligned and there to be a slight space separating the description from the next "row".

I've managed to:

- block floats from coming in between the "table" (although unsure if implemented correctly) using `placeins`
- prevent page breaks in awkward places (in header row, after header row, after second to last row) by applying penalties in the appropriate places.
- allow for an arbitrary number of arguments (provided that the left two are always left-aligned, a criterion that falls within my acceptability)
- using `[t]` or `[b]` as args to `\parbox` also results in whitespace, which leads me to believe there is something implicit going on here.

## Problem

How can I remove the glue around the descriptions? I'd like to fix the spacing between them. I suppose I could deal with a little glue after each description, but not much! The pseudo-table should look uniform.

The solution should take aesthetics into account:

- descriptions have a left uniform indent
- descriptions have a right uniform indent

## Code

*Please note that, in hindsight, I am aware that my table contains acronyms, NOT abbreviations ;)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% because XeLaTeX
\usepackage{xparse}% for the LaTeX3 syntax
\usepackage{environ}% for capturing everything within an environment in \BODY
\usepackage{booktabs}% for the \heavyrulewidth and \midrulewidth
\usepackage{lipsum}% for the dummy text
\usepackage{placeins}% to keep floats out of ifodescriptionlist

% Counters
\newcounter{ifodescriptionlistcounter}
% Lengths
\newlength{\originalparskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\ifoitemx}{ O{} m }
  {% The redefinition of ithitem. Optional:comma list of values; mandatory:description. For use inside of ifodescriptionlist
  \par\noindent\doithitemargs:n{#1}% Handle comma list with LaTeX3 xparse
  \par\nobreak
  \hspace{5mm}\hangindent=5mm{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}{\footnotesize #2}\par}% This #2 represents the descriptions
  \addtocounter{ifodescriptionlistcounter}{-1}% descrease count while it is increased
  \ifnum\value{ifodescriptionlistcounter}<2 \nobreak \fi
  }%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ifodescriptionlist}{ O{} O{} }
  {% See ifodescriptionlistBODY to capture contents (\BODY) of environment
  \FloatBarrier % Prevent floats to break this environment
  \setcounter{ifodescriptionlistcounter}{0}% Reset counter
  \par\bigskip %paragraph ensures start of fresh paragraph, bigskip adds vertical padding after new paragraph (related to vspace below table caption)
  \setlength{\originalparskip}{\parskip}% save the value
  \setlength{\parskip}{1pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}% remove the \parskip glue
  \hrule height\heavyrulewidth\nobreak%\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
  \smallskip\nobreak
  \hbox to \hsize{\bf #1}\nobreak
  \smallskip\nobreak
  \hrule height\lightrulewidth\nobreak  %\noindent\rule[2mm]{\textwidth}{\lightrulewidth}\par\nobreak
  \medskip\nobreak
  \ifodescriptionlistBODY\endifodescriptionlistBODY% Capture contents (\BODY) and localize with {}
  }
  {
  \medskip
  \hrule height\heavyrulewidth
  \nobreak
  \smallskip
  {\tiny #2}
  \setlength{\parskip}{\originalparskip}% restore the value
  \FloatBarrier % Prevent floats to break this environment
  \par
  }
\NewEnviron{ifodescriptionlistBODY}% from environ Package NewEnviron
  {% environ package is the only way I know how to grab the body like in TeX
    \def\ifoitem[##1]##2{\addtocounter{ifodescriptionlistcounter}{1}}% Define ithitem to add 1 to counter each call
    \interlinepenalty=10000 % Change interlinepenalty for this local environment (all ithitems)
    \typeout{**** Value ifodescriptionlistcounter (before first call of body): \the\value{ifodescriptionlistcounter}} % Log+Terminal entry
    \BODY % Typeset body of env (empty), just calls ithitems within contained within \BODY.
    \typeout{**** Value ifodescriptionlistcounter (after first call of body): \the\value{ifodescriptionlistcounter}} % Log+Terminal entry
    \let\ifoitem=\ifoitemx% Redefine ithitem to ithitemx
    \BODY % Retypeset body of env with new definition of \ifoitem
    % The rest continues in the main environment
  }{}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% LaTeX3 expl3 processing
%
\ExplSyntaxOn % Handler for ifodescriptionlist
\clist_new:N\ifoitemargs % Initialize comma list
\cs_new_protected:Nn\doithitemargs:n
  {
    {%
      \clist_set:Nn \ifoitemargs {#1}%
      \textbf{\clist_item:Nn \ifoitemargs {1}},~\clist_item:Nn \ifoitemargs {2} \hfill \int_step_inline:nnnn {3}{1}{\clist_count:N \ifoitemargs}
      {%
        \int_compare:nTF { ##1 = \clist_count:N \ifoitemargs }% Decide whether or not last item has been reached.
          {\clist_item:Nn \ifoitemargs {##1}}
          {\clist_item:Nn \ifoitemargs {##1},~}
      }
    }
  }%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{ifodescriptionlist}[Abbreviation, Name \hfill B/S, Rep\#][B~=~Big, S~=~Small, Rep\#~=~Whether or not a rep number has been assigned.]

\ifoitem[RIS, Radiological Information System, B, N]
  {\lipsum[1]}
\ifoitem[CORBA, Common Object Request Broker Architecture, B, N]
  {\lipsum[2]}
\ifoitem[GPU, Ground Power Unit, B, Y]
  {Which one of these things is not like the other?}
\ifoitem[PACS, Picture Archiving Communication System , S, Y]
  {\lipsum[3]}
\ifoitem[SCP, Service Class Provider, S, N]
  {\lipsum[4]}
\end{ifodescriptionlist}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

## Output with `\parbox[t]`

You'll notice that the descriptions seemed "pushed" downwards to the next row. Doesn't `t` stand for top-aligned? **Where is this whitespace coming from?**

[image]

## Output with `\parbox[b]`

You'll notice that the space is uneven again, maybe because the parbox is bottom-aligned.

[image]

Comment: @egreg The solution to the other question does not solve my issue. I already tried using parameters with `\parbox`. Some mysterious whitespace remains. I also tried resetting the `\prevdepth`. Are you sure that applies to my situation? Please see edits. Maybe they warrant reopening this question.

Comment: Yes, it surely solves the issue: this is [the picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4nXNo.png) of what I get with a proper redefinition of the macro, basically `\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}{\footnotesize #2\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}}\par\prevdepth=\tpd`

Comment: @egreg Ah! Of course! The `\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` must happen within the scope of `\footnotesize` in order to capture its `\lineskip` value (or something, davidcarlisle explained it to me once). That means the mysterious whitespace above was caused by the larger `\lineskip` value of the normal font. Could you confirm this?

Comment: @egreg I think the culprit was the `\par\noindent` before the `\hspace{5mm}\hangindent=5mm{\parbox...`